# Swift UI Problem displaying data from parsed json

Tags: json, swift, foreach, jsondecoder

I am new to swift and I have built a simple ui off an example that I had typed out and knew to be working, but when I substitute my own data and write my own model it breaks down.
I have linted my JSON and it is valid. My UI throws an error `Value of type 'Resorts' has no member 'items'`. The trouble I am having is looping through the json objects with a `ForEach` and displaying `items.resortName`

Any help would be HUGE!

Here is my code:

ContentModel

```
import Foundation

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var resorts = [Resorts]()
    
    init() {

        getLocalData()
    }
    
    func getLocalData() {
        
        // Get a url to the json file
        let jsonUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
        
        do {
            // Read the file into a data object
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonUrl!)
            
            // Try to decode the json into an array of modules
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let resorts = try jsonDecoder.decode([Resorts].self, from: jsonData)
            
            // Assign parsed modules to modules property
            self.resorts = resorts
        }
        catch {
            // TODO log error
            print("Couldn't parse local data \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Resorts

```
import Foundation

struct Resorts: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var apiVersion: String
    var region: Region
    
}

struct Region: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var items: [Items]
    
}

struct Items: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var resortName: String
    var state: String
    
}
```

JSON Snippet

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "apiVersion": "12.2",
        "region": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Rocky Mountains",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "resortName": "A Basin",
                    "state": "Colorado",
                    "reportDateTime": "2021-06-05 06:25:00",
                    "resortStatus": "minutes",
                    "operationStatus": "8",
                ...
```

Content View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: DataModel

    var body: some View {
       
        Text("Hello")
        ScrollView {
            
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(model.resorts) { resort in
                    ZStack {
                        
                        Color.white
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                        VStack {
                            Text("Resort by name")
                            //                        Text(resort.items)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 175, height: 100)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Text(resort.items). try to use Text(resort.region.items).
your resort does not have items

Comment: I am actually trying to get to the name of the resort in the item array. But thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may have solved my issue. But I am guessing there has to be a more elegant solution to drilling down into a JSON array of objects then what I did...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: DataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .blue, .purple]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    ForEach(model.resorts) { resort in
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("Resort by name")
                            Text(resort.region.name)
                            ForEach(Array(resort.region.items)) { ski in
                                
                                ZStack {
                                    
                                    Color.white
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                    
                                    Text(ski.resortName)
                                    
                                }
                                .frame(width: 175, height: 100)
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
}
```